# VB.Net DataTable.Select specific value or DBNull

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

I'm trying to use `DataTable.Select` to extract rows having the field (of string) named 'GivenAnswer' not equal to 'A' (even if empty or DBNull).

I've tried:

```
Dim SelRows() As Datarow = QTable.Select("GivenAnswer <> 'A'")
```

But it returns no rows

I've checked that rows having `GivenAnswer = DBNull` aren't caught but I wasn't able to find the right syntax for the filter expression

I've tried:

```
 "GivenAnswer <> 'A' OR GivenAnswer = ''" --> No Rows 
 "GivenAnswer <> 'A' OR GivenAnswer = Null" --> No Rows
 "GivenAnswer <> 'A' OR GivenAnswer = DBNull" --> Column DBNull not found
 "GivenAnswer <> 'A' OR GivenAnswer is DBNull" --> Column DBNull not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ISNULL`

```
Dim SelRows() As Datarow = QTable.Select("ISNULL(GivenAnswer, '') <> 'A'")
```

For an overview of supported exporessions look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

But i'd prefer LINQ:

```
Dim filteredRows = From row In QTable.AsEnumerable()
                   Where row.Field(Of String)("GivenAnswer") <> "A"
Dim SelRows() As Datarow = filteredRows.ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks, even for linq solution (I'll try it) I'll accept as soon as possible ;)